# How to generate credentials.json in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to use Google Storage for my Django application deployed in Compute Engine. To enable this I have to download a [credentials.json](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html#getting-started) in my console. I have made a new service account. However I do not see any download json for this credentials. How do you generate the json file?

Comment: You do not need a service account key file. It's especially a bad pattern to use a service account key file (security breach) but especially when you are on Google Cloud environment. Use ADC instead. Keep in mind that, most of the time, you don't need a service account key file, it's only in very rare cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on the relevant service account in [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) and create a new key from <kbd>KEYS</kbd> tab by clicking <kbd>Add Key</kbd>. Once you create the key, the JSON file will be downloaded.

[image]

Checkout the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for more information if you want to create keys programmatically.

---

As @Guillaume commented, if you are running your application in Google Cloud env, then you use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication).